# How to store history answer data in sql database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

I have a system whereby it can set the open and close dates allowing user to go in and submit answer for survey. The system also wants to delete the most current records from the database.

**Example:**

Person A:

- 1st survey: submitted on JAN/2011
- 2nd survey: submitted on MAR/2012
- 3rd, 4th...

How can i make sure that data are stored securely and able to retrieve past records and still able to delete latest?

I am thinking of storing latest data on one database and the history data on another database where it could be permanent. But then if records continue to be submitted, will it affect the search if there are more and more data stored? Any suggestion please? Heard about sql08 auditing? does it work?

Comment: Just one: Buy a book, browse the web and follow some tutorial with regards to beginning using databases :). A single database seems like the way to go in this case

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want to store them in separate databases, and why would the history be any different than the latest? Just store all their answers for all time.

For the most simple example, if it's a single table for a survey, just store their user id, a unique survey id, and the date that it was submitted. When you want to get the most recent, get the Top 1 sorted by the submit date in descending order.

Comment: but will it affect the search performance when i have data kept coming in and not going out?

Comment: Prototype and measure. I.e. bad choice of indexes will have much higher impact on performance than couple extra records.

Comment: You don't need to delete data to keep it performant. Even a table scan will be pretty much unnoticeable for a long time, so unless you have millions of records, you don't need to worry about it.